# Cumulative operations on dtype objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how I can apply cumulative functions to objects. For numbers there are several alternatives like `cumsum` and `cumcount`. There is also [df.expanding](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) which can be used with `apply`. But the functions I pass to `apply` do not work on objects.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"C1": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   "C2": [{"A"}, {"B"}, {"C"}, {"D"}], 
                   "C3": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
                   "C4": [["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["D"]]})

df
Out: 
   C1   C2 C3   C4
0   1  {A}  A  [A]
1   2  {B}  B  [B]
2   3  {C}  C  [C]
3   4  {D}  D  [D]
```

In the dataframe I have integer values, sets, strings and lists. Now, if I try `expanding().apply(sum)` I have the cumulative sum:

```
df.expanding().apply(sum)
Out[69]: 
     C1   C2 C3   C4
0   1.0  {A}  A  [A]
1   3.0  {B}  B  [B]
2   6.0  {C}  C  [C]
3  10.0  {D}  D  [D]
```

My expectation was, since summation is defined on lists and strings, I would get something like this:

```
     C1   C2  C3     C4
0   1.0  {A}  A      [A]
1   3.0  {B}  AB     [A, B]
2   6.0  {C}  ABC    [A, B, C]
3  10.0  {D}  ABCD   [A, B, C, D]
```

I also tried something like this:

```
df.expanding().apply(lambda r: reduce(lambda x, y: x+y**2, r))
Out: 
     C1   C2 C3   C4
0   1.0  {A}  A  [A]
1   5.0  {B}  B  [B]
2  14.0  {C}  C  [C]
3  30.0  {D}  D  [D]
```

It works as I expect: previous result is `x` and the current row value is `y`. But I cannot reduce using `x.union(y)`, for example.

So, my question is: Are there any alternatives to `expanding` that I can use on objects? The example is just to show that `expanding().apply()` is not working on object dtypes. I am looking for a general solution that supports applying functions to those two inputs: previous result and the current element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this cannot be done.

Continuing on the same sample:

```
def burndowntheworld(ser):
    print('Are you sure?')
    return ser/0

df.select_dtypes(['object']).expanding().apply(burndowntheworld)
Out: 
    C2 C3   C4
0  {A}  A  [A]
1  {B}  B  [B]
2  {C}  C  [C]
3  {D}  D  [D]
```

If the column's type is object, the function is never called. And pandas doesn't have an alternative that works on objects. It's the same for [`rolling().apply()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723003/why-doesnt-my-pandas-rolling-apply-work-when-the-series-contains-collection).

In some sense, this is a good thing because `expanding.apply` with a custom function has O(n**2) complexity. With special cases like `cumsum`, `ewma` etc, the recursive nature of the operations can decrease the complexity to linear time but in the most general case it should calculate the function for the first n elements, and then for the first n+1 elements and so on. Therefore, especially for a function which is only dependent on the current value and function's previous value, expanding is quite inefficient. Not to mention storing lists or sets in a DataFrame is never a good idea to begin with.

So the answer is: if your data is not numeric and the function is dependent on the previous result and the current element, just use a for loop. It will be more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with exception `set`, then you need first convert to `list` and then to `set`. Btw, storing `set` (`C2`) or `lists` of `lists` (`C4`) in columns in `DataFrame` is not recommended.

```
print df
   C1   C2 C3   C4
0   1  {A}  A  [A]
1   2  {B}  B  [B]
2   3  {C}  C  [C]
3   4  {D}  D  [D]

print df[['C1','C3','C4']].cumsum()
   C1    C3            C4
0   1     A           [A]
1   3    AB        [A, B]
2   6   ABC     [A, B, C]
3  10  ABCD  [A, B, C, D]

df['C2'] = df['C2'].apply(list)
df = df.cumsum()
df['C2'] = df['C2'].apply(set)
print df
   C1            C2    C3            C4
0   1           {A}     A           [A]
1   3        {A, B}    AB        [A, B]
2   6     {A, C, B}   ABC     [A, B, C]
3  10  {A, C, B, D}  ABCD  [A, B, C, D]
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you can define a custom function

```
def custom_cumsum(df):
    from functools import reduce
    nrows, ncols = df.shape
    index, columns = df.index, df.columns
    rets = {}
    new_col = None
    for col in df.columns:
        try:
            new_col = {col:df.loc[:, col].cumsum()}
        except TypeError as e:
            if 'set' in str(e):
                new_col = {col:[ reduce(set.union, df.loc[:, col][:(i+1)]) for i in range(nrows)]}
        rets.update(new_col)
    frame = pd.DataFrame(rets, index=index, columns=columns)
    return frame
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess the example is a little misleading. I included that example to show that `expanding().apply()` is not working on objects. I am looking for an alternative to `expanding().apply()` that works on objects, too.