# Why doesn't my pandas rolling().apply() work when the series contains collections?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas series in which each cell is a tuple.  I'm trying to do a rolling().apply() on that series, and the function I'm trying to apply is never getting called.  Here's a silly example that shows what I'm talking about:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
u'0.18.0'
>>> die = lambda x: 0/0

>>> s = pd.Series(zip(range(5), range(5)))
>>> s
0    (0, 0)
1    (1, 1)
2    (2, 2)
3    (3, 3)
4    (4, 4)
dtype: object
```

A simple `apply` works as expected, in that the function is called:

```
>>> s.apply(die)
[...]
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

But but a `rolling().apply()` does nothing at all, and in particular the function that is supposed to be applied never gets called:

```
>>> s.rolling(2).apply(die)
0    (0, 0)
1    (1, 1)
2    (2, 2)
3    (3, 3)
4    (4, 4)
dtype: object
```

This is the simplest example that demonstrates what I'm talking about, but the same thing happens with sets & lists.

Why does this happen, and how can I do a rolling apply with a custom function on a series of collections?

Comment: I believe rolling().apply() and expanding().apply() are not implemented for objects. I asked a similar question few hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/q/36717416/2285236

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because the [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function returns  *a Window or Rolling sub-classed for the particular operation* while [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) *Applies function along input axis of DataFrame*. As mentioned by ayhan, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717416/cumulative-operations-on-dtype-objects) post.