# Applying rolling to a Series of lists

Tags: python, pandas, series, rolling-computation

Assume that you have some code:

```
def test(x):
    # some function that operates on a list of lists
    # and returns a value

import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series([1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9])
x = data.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: test(x))
print(x)
```

When the above code is run, `x` is always equal to `data`.  It is as though the rolling function is never applied.

How can one apply a rolling (or expanding) function like this to a Pandas Series?

Comment: Show your expected output ~

Comment: No, you cannot use rolling.apply or expanding.apply if the dtype is object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723003/why-doesnt-my-pandas-rolling-apply-work-when-the-series-contains-collection

Comment: Hi @ayhan, do you have any recommendations for working around this?

Comment: I use a regular loop. Especially for expanding it is [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654731/2285236) anyway.