# Get value count over time in pandas with rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the "value popularity" over time in a Pandas Dataframe.

```
Key RandomColumn
a   0
b   ...
c   does
d   not
a   matter
e   ...
c   ...
```

I want to use a lets, say, rolling window of 2 and count the number of times "this" value (from the row in question, has been seen).

Output:

```
Key RandomColumn Popularity
a   0            0
b   ...          0
c   does         0
d   not          0
a   matter       0  <--- outside past window of 2
d   ...          1
c   ...          0  <-- outside window too
c   ....         1
c   ....         2
```

I have been trying things like *groupby* but then I lose the sliding, I can get the sliding with *rolling* but then not so sure how to aggregate and return.

Last attempt I endup with something like:

```
df['popularity']=df.groupby('key').cumcount().rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()
```

But that is clearly wrong.

I can always use a *for-loop*, or maybe *apply* with indexing and manual count, but wondering if there is a "proper" way to do it in Pandas.

Update: Example #2: "Count the number of times a given value X has been seen in the past N-records", for simplicity, lets say N=2

```
For the Series: [a, b, b, c, d, a, b, c, c, c, a, b]
The output is:  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

First 2 zeros (0, 0) as, a and b, has never seen before, then (1) *b* has seen 1 time in the past 2 values and so on.

Comment: Could you make a clearer example? I don't understand what you want to count

Comment: I tried to update a new example and a literal interpretation in text of the required calculation.

Comment: If N=3,,,, Does A,B,A return [0,0,1] since A is seen within the window even it it isn't consecutive?

Comment: @ScottBoston, correct, also the window is "past N" rows, so, in your example even N=2 returns 0,0,1, because its N into the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you cannot use `rolling` with non numeric objects. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654731/10426037).
So for a general solution where you can choose your `N`, the `for` loop is probably the best approach.

You can define a function such as:

```
def popularitycount(sr, n):
    """sr is an iterable (a list, tuple, or pandas Series), n an integer"""
    previous = []
    res = []
    for el in sr:
        res.append(previous.count(el))
        previous.append(el)
        if len(previous) > n:
            previous.pop(0)
    return pd.Series(res)
```

Using your input, this returns the following `Series`:

```
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     2
10    0
11    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`shift()`**, **`rolling`** & **`np.where`**:

1. First we mark all the rows where the previous row is equal to the current one with `.shift`
2. We calculate the rolling sum with `.rolling`
3. We conditionally fill in 0 if the previous row is not equal to current one to correct some rows, since `rolling(2)` drags on 1 row too far.

```
m1 = df.eq(df.shift())
m2 = df.eq(df.shift()).rolling(2).sum()

df['Popularity'] = np.where(m1, m2, 0).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
   Key  Popularity
0    a           0
1    b           0
2    b           1
3    c           0
4    d           0
5    a           0
6    b           0
7    c           0
8    c           1
9    c           2
10   a           0
11   b           0
```

---

**Input dataframe used**:

```
   Key
0    a
1    b
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    a
6    b
7    c
8    c
9    c
10   a
11   b
```

Comment: I dont think this works, the previous row is always irrelevant, its not about counting "continuous repeated values" when N=5000, for instance, its clear, in the sample frame I used N=2 just for simplicity, my use case it's actually N>3500